# Get the request URL in a JSF bean?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

How do you get the request URL in a bean backing a JSF page? I've been looking through the FacesContext docs and the best way I could find seems terribly long:

```
public String getRequestURL()
{
    Object request = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
    {
            return ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
    }else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Edit: Functional Requirements** The requirement here is that we need the full URL for a third party javascript utility. The use or architecture of the utility doesn't fit well with JSF, but everything short of this call does. The method I found will work, but it felt wrong to be digging so deep into the FacesContext. Additionally I was hoping there would be a way that could be called with JSF Expression Language since this is going to be used in a "view" related way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you ever need to haul the raw Servlet API from under the JSF hoods by the `FacesContext`, then chances are that you're doing the job at the wrong place. What is it, the functional requirement for which you thought that this is the right solution? Should you maybe not be using a real `Servlet` class or a `Filter` instead of a JSF managed bean? Or maybe don't you need the request URL at all because there are better "jsfish" ways to achieve the same?

If you update your question to include the detail about the functional requirement, then we may be able to suggest the right solution.

---

**Update** as per your edit: so, you just need it after all in the view side? E.g. `#{bean.requestURL}`? You can also just grab it from the `HttpServletRequest` object which is already implicitly available in EL.

When you're on JSP:

```
${pageContext.request.requestURL}
```

Or when you're on Facelets:

```
#{request.requestURL}
```

And now, how do you need it for JavaScript? Printing as a JavaScript variable? Like so?

```
var url = '#{request.requestURL}';
```

If so, you could also just grab [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) for that.

```
var url = window.location;
```

No need to clutter the JSF bean with the view specific details.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up all the various methods of pulling it out!

Comment: I was able to work around it in the end, but I would have used window.location

Answer (score 3):

You already have you answer :) I'm afraid you'll have to use it that way, since every HTTP request will have to be retrieve from the faces context. You could, of course, simplify some part of this method, like the faces context retrieval, but its definitively the way to go, unless you use some kind of framework that abstracts away those details and let you get to the HttpRequest Object directly.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you can get url with all parameters so:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getRequest();
String url = req.getHeader("referer");
```