# HTTP Requests in JSF

Tags: android, jsf, send, http-request

I have an JSF web application that needs to get some information from a native android app.

I've read about creating HTTP requests in android, and I think I can figure it out, but I have no clue on what to do on the JSF side of things. Do I create a new page, bean or what? Is http requests even the proper way to go?

I simply want to send a string from the Android app, to the JSF web app and store it in a bean  somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Additional info
Using Android API 16
JBoss Server 7.1
Eclipse
JSF

Comment: I don't know how to do this with plain JSF, but IMO you could create a Servlet to process your HTTP request.

Comment: Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3302933/1065197), the best approach for your case should be creating a raw Servlet or maybe a Filter, IMO I would use a Servlet.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have no idea what a servlet is, so how exactly would I go about doing this? Is there some examples that you can point me to? I have my JSF app in eclipse at the moment, is there a certain file I create, or do I write something inside a web page?

Comment: Check the basic info for Servlets in [our wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF is a component based MVC framework for HTML form based applications. What you're concretely asking is more a job for a web service, not a HTML form controller. JSF is not a web service framework and is hence the wrong tool for the job. You're better off using [JAX-WS](http://metro.java.net/) (SOAP) or [JAX-RS](http://jersey.java.net/) (RESTful) or maybe even "plain vanilla" [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Then, to let your JSF web application share the same data, just use the same data store (DB).